# What is an HTTP Proxy (forward not reverse) required to do with a client's request headers?

Tags: proxy, http-headers, transparent-proxy

1

Could someone help me distill down what, exactly, the minimum requirements are for a proxy server (just a forward proxy not reverse) with regard to headers? What headers absolutely must be deleted from the client request before it's passed upstream by the proxy server?

I'm trying to make sense of the rfc2616 doc but it's slightly impenetrable to me and I've yet to find any blogs or articles that just isolate what the requirements or expectations are for a proxy server with regard to headers.

Comment: Bad news: RFC 2616 is obsolete, replaced by RFC 7230-7235 inclusive. You should no longer use RFC 2616 as a normative reference. If you're implementing a proxy server then you absolutely need to have a good understanding of all of this.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Not my call, a project I've been tasked with is pointing me towards RFC2616. So a lot has changed regarding proxy servers in RFC 7230-7235 or is that just a general statement?

Comment: Mostly it's better organized now, with numerous bits clarified. You should not use the obsolete document as anything but a historical reference, even if someone pointed you to it.